# How to include modified configuration files in a docker image?

Tags: git, docker, wso2, docker-image

I am new to Docker. A devop colleague has created a WSO2 docker image in a github repository. He uses such images to create staging and production instances.

The `docker-compose.yml` is:

```
#openssl req        -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout domain.key        -x509 -days 365 -out domain.crt

version: '2'

services:
  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7.10
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    volumes:
      - ./docker-entrypoint-initdb.d:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
    environment:
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=userdb
      - MYSQL_USER=dbwso2am
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=dbwso2am
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=dbwso2am
  wso2am:
    image: salte/wso2am:1.9.1
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    volumes:
      - ./keys:/keys
    environment:
      - VIRTUAL_HOST=apimanager.qa.xxx.build
      - VIRTUAL_PORT=9443
      - VIRTUAL_PROTO=https
      - OFFSET=3
      - EXTERNAL_HOSTNAME=apimanager.qa.xxx.build
      - DATABASE_HOSTNAME=mysql
      - DATABASE_PORT=3306
      - DATABASE_USER=dbwso2am
      - DATABASE_PASSWORD=dbwso2am
      - PUBLIC_CERTIFICATE=/keys/domain.crt
      - PRIVATE_KEY=/keys/domain.key
      - PRIVATE_KEY_PASSWORD=wso2am
      - ADMIN_PASSWORD=admin
```

I would like to modify some WSO2 [configuration](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM1100/Configuring+Caching) stored in some `xml` file and push it to production.

How should I proceed? Is this possible? Should I modify the docker image? If yes how? Or should I install WSO2 in a classic github repository, modify the `xml` there and re-create a docker image based on this repository's content?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to create anew the entire image just to change one xml.
You can replace it through volumes or command.
For example i have linked shared folder and you can run commands on the container.
Let say you have Share folder in /home/share and its linked to /c/Share
So you put your new xml file in Share and the container can see it too.
Next you run this command:

```
docker exec a5866aee4e90 cp -i /home/share/some.xml /home/the/path/you/chose
```

Docker exec is used to run commands.
You can enter the console and run multiple commands with this:

```
docker exec -it a5866aee4e90 bash
```

Comment: How do you do that folder share thing?

Comment: Add to the yml file this config - 
volumes:
            - /c/Users/richardkovachev/Documents/workspace/myskrill:/home/mb/myskrill:rw 

or if you run it with docker command :

docker run -it --rm=true --name my_name -v  /c/Users/richardkovachev/Desktop:/home/share

Answer (score 0):

`docker cp`: https://github.com/docker/docker/pull/6580

Steps (assuming you need to modify an existing config file. If not then start on step 2):

1. copy the config file out of the container to the host.
   (This can be done in multiple ways: `docker cp`, simple console window copy-paste, volume sharing)
2. modify the config file with an editor on the host
3. copy back the modified file to the container with `docker cp`

Before you resort to this, always try to apply the modifications through environment variables. If that's not possible, then you have to revert to editing.